# AWS Cloud Search Search Index Domain Split Across 12 Partitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudsearch

Currently using `AWS CloudSearch` for internal project. I got approx. 300 TB data that need to be ingested into `CloudSearch`.

After developing the `Java` Batch job to ingest data into `CloudSearch` via given `Document Endpoint` I used below options as default to make `AWS` do the scaling up and down according to the requests.

[image]

Engine Type Using: CloudSearch (2013 API)

According to AWS Documentation it is mentioned maxium `paritions` number is 10 where as I see 12 paritions now.

[image]

I tried round the clock but yet could not find static information on this. Appreciate anyone could assist me with below questions.

I can see `maxium` instance type is used 2x.Large but how to find how many `EC2` of this type are doing the ingestion into CloudSearch?

Since I`m worried about the cost, if Documentation mentions 10 maxium paritions why I got 12?